# Why is 32-bit pointer sign-extended when cast to uint64_t?

Tags: c, pointers, casting

When compiled as a 32-bit process, the following code prints `ffffffff82223333` instead of `82223333`, so it seems like a pointer is always sign-extended when converted to `uint64_t`. Why is that?

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    void *p = (void*) 0x82223333;
    uint64_t x = (uint64_t) p;
    printf("%llx\n", x);
}
```

I thought an address can never be negative, so it should be treated as unsigned.

My question is also related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43012454/7571258) (because Windows handles are just typedefs for pointers).

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7677919/7571258), but still no explanation why the compiler developers choose to do this.

Comment: I can't reproduce here; can you share more details of your environment?

Comment: @Carl Windows with VS2017.

Comment: Your reasoning seems a little reversed - whether addresses can be negative or not is a question that you can only answer *after* deciding whether to treat them as signed or unsigned. Anyway [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384242(v=vs.85).aspx) mentions that it's normal, but does not explain why this choice was made.

Comment: The high-order 32-bits have no meaning in a 32-bit process, so the compiler ought to be able to do whatever it likes.  The only guarantees you have with pointers is that if you convert one to a sufficiently-sized integer (e.g. `intptr_t`) and then back to a pointer, you get the same address again.

Comment: @paddy Yes, it's clear that this is implementation-dependent behaviour, but *why* did they choose to do this?

Comment: @zett42 It might not have been a deliberate choice. It might happen to be a consequence of how the typecasting code is written to cover more valid cases.

Comment: what is `sizeof(void *)` on your system ? Try `printf("%p\n", p);`

Comment: @M.M it's 4 bytes

Comment: Maybe it handles pointer-integer conversion by converting the pointer to `long` and then converting that result to whatever type is requested

Comment: Why does it matter?  If you absolutely require the number to have its top bits cleared, then use a bitmask.  But beware that masking and then converting back to a pointer might be undefined behaviour.

Comment: @paddy I'm just curious because OP of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43012454/7571258) observed that behaviour and I couldn't really explain it. His question is solved by casting to `uint32_t` instead because handles are always 32-bit. In general I think I can live with "it's implementation-defined behaviour". Thanks.

Comment: My guess: 32 bit windows uses top half as kernel memory, and 64 bit windows uses top half of the "canonical form addresses " as kernel memory. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#VIRTUAL-ADDRESS-SPACE). Possibly Windows is trying to use this convention to map kernel/user 32 bit addresses to kernel/user 64 bit addresses respectively. Use case? To support legacy 32 bit kernel mode driver ABI? Maybe?

Comment: More: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384242(v=vs.85).aspx  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447812/pointer-32-what-is-it-and-why