# Can a reinterpret_cast change the object representation?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

My mental model for a `reinterpret_cast` has always been, to treat the sequence of bits of an expression as if they were of a different type, and [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) (note: this is not a quote from the C++ Standard) seems to agree with that:

> Unlike `static_cast`, but like `const_cast`, the `reinterpret_cast` expression does not compile to any CPU instructions. It is purely a compiler directive which instructs the compiler to treat the sequence of bits (object representation) of *expression* as if it had the type *new_type*.

Looking for guarantees, I stumbled across a note under [[expr.reinterpret.cast]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#3):

> [ *Note*: The mapping performed by `reinterpret_­cast` might, or might not, produce a representation different from the original value. — *end note* ]

That left me wondering: Under which conditions does a `reinterpret_cast` produce a value with object representation different from the original value?

Comment: No casts change the object they are applied to, if that is what you are asking.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: I don't feel, that edit adds anything that wasn't there already.

Comment: Immediately comes to mind a situation when different pointer types have different alignment requirements and actively zero out the low-order bits. On such platform casting from a less strict alignment requirement to a more strict alignment requirement will zero out some bits.

Comment: @AnT: That helped me understand, why `reinterpret_cast` round-tripping (`T1*` → `T2*` → `T1*`) is only guaranteed to return the same object representation, in case `T2`'s alignment requirements are no stricter than `T1`'s. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an example: if you read the [4th](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#4) bullet point:

> A pointer can be explicitly converted to any integral type large enough to hold all values of its type. The mapping function is implementation-defined. [ Note: It is intended to be unsurprising to those who know the addressing structure of the underlying machine. — end note ]

Now, it is implementation defined, what value of `i` will have here:

```
void *ptr = <some valid pointer value>;
uintptr_t i = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(ptr);
```

It can be anything, provided that `reinterpret_cast`ing `i` back we'll get `ptr`.

The representation of `ptr` and `i` could differ. The standard just says that the value of `i` should be "unsurprising". Even, if we `reinterpret_cast` `ptr` to a wider integer (for example, if a pointer is 32-bit, casting to `unsigned long long int`), the representation **must** differ, because the size of the variables differ.

So I think that cppreference description is misleading, because there can be `reinterpret_cast`s, which actually need CPU instructions.

---

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399003/is-the-sizeofsome-pointer-always-equal-to-four/399122#comment14833666_399122) is another case (found by IInspectable), a comment by Keith Thompson:

> The C compiler for Cray vector machines, such as the T90, do something similar. Hardware addresses are 8 bytes, and point to 8-byte words. void* and char* are handled in software, and are augmented with a 3-bit offset within the word -- but since there isn't actually a 64-bit address space, the offset is stored in the high-order 3 bits of the 64-bit word. So **char* and int* are the same size, but have different internal representations** -- and code that assumes that pointers are "really" just integers can fail badly.

`char *` and `int *` have different representations on Cray T90, so:

```
int *i = <some int pointer value>;
char *c = reinterpret_cast<char *>(i);
```

Here, `i` and `c` will have differing representations on Cray T90 (and doing this conversion definitely uses CPU instructions).

(I've verified this, chapter 3.1.2.7.1 of [Cray C/C++ Reference Manual SR–2179 2.0](ftp://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/parallel/t3e/doc/SR2179.20.ps.gz))

Comment: I still don't see how reinterpret_cast  is supposed to magically do these compile-time type conversions. And this question can be quite simply answered by someone posting the emitted assembler code that illustrates when it does.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: what do you mean by "magically"? In my example, we have a pointer. It is converted to integer. The mapping is implementation defined, can be anything. So, representation can be anything as well, i.e., it can change. End of story.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: Given `#include <stdint>` / `uint64_t foo(void *x) { return reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>(x); }`, Apple LLVM 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2) invoked with `c++ -O3 -m32 -S` generates `movl 8(%ebp), %eax` / `xorl %edx, %edx`, thus taking as input a four-byte object and producing as output an eight-byte object.

Comment: Note: notes are non-normative.  Compilers are free to disregard them and they are still C++ standard compliant.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: I've seen this note several times, where is this information written? I mean, which part is normative and which is not in the standard (supposedly parts between '[' and ']' are non-normative)? I haven't found it in the C++ standard itself. Is it in some referenced document?

Comment: @gaza https://stackoverflow.com/q/21364398/1774667 -- it is an iso standard thing

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: Thanks! For almost any question, there is an answer at SO already :)

Comment: Could you also add a somewhat unexpected case on word-addressed architectures, like explained in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399003/is-the-sizeofsome-pointer-always-equal-to-four/399122#comment14833666_399122)?

Comment: @IInspectable: nice find, I've added some information to my answer.

Comment: _" if we reinterpret_cast ptr to a wider integer"_ -- the MSVC 14.1 compiler even does a [sign-extension of the pointer value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43035539/7571258), a good example of how the representation can change !

Answer (score -3):

You are correct that reinterpret_cast does not change the bit values, however that doesn't mean the resulting value doesn't change.

One simple example would be casting a 32-bit integral type to a char[4] with each element representing one octet of an IPv4 address.

Comment: How is that a simple example? Explain more.

Comment: That cast - to my knowledge - preserves the object representation.

Comment: Actually, you misread the question. It does explicitly say, that a cast can change the object representation (the bit values).